# How o bind data like this... <ul><li>binded data</li></ul>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to bind some data from a stored procedure into ul elements to  display them as contents of a list. I am not able to do it. Please help me. The code I am using is:

(ASPX)HTML code

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:label runat="server" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ID="LblInventoryNumber" Text="Inventory Number"></asp:label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" id="TxtInventoryNumber" placeholder="Number" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img src="images/icon-add-on-1.png" alt="" /></a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="ul" runat="server">
                                                          <li><a href="javascript:;">Action</a></li>
                                                          <li><a href="javascript:;">Another action</a></li>
                                                          <li><a href="javascript:;">Something else here</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

In place, the C# code is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    string com = "Select SiteID from IC_INVENTORY_T ";

    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    adpt.Fill(dt);

    ul.DataSource = dt;

   ul .DataBind();

    ul.DataTextField = "SiteID";

    ul.DataValueField = "SiteID";
    ul.DataBind();
```

Please help me on this...

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: Welcome. You'll need to tell us what the problem is. We're not a free debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

Where as your question is totally not clear, still if you are using datatable to keep the data after execution, you can use source binding . e.g-->
Code Sample

```
 <ul>
        <%
    for(int I=0; I< dt.rows.count;i++)
    {%>
    <li><%dt.rows[i][column_name].ToString()%></li> 
    <li><%dt.rows[i][column_name].ToString()%></li>     


<%}%>
</ul>
```

In this way you can show somewhat.... **But be clear**

Answer (score 0):

Try using foreach

```
foreach item in com
{
    <li>item.coloumname</li>
}
```

hope it's help and... many source to do this and keep practice

Comment: Hi Shiroze, The problem is, The _click event is not working

Comment: you didn't add the javascript function... add the js function in the bottom of your code.. like ardila says... we're not a free debuging service.